# How to retrieve values from dialog ListView...?

Tags: android

I'm showing a list using dialog...the list contains `Text View` and `Edit Text` widgets and a (Done)`Button`.

Clicking on (Done)`Button` will retrieve those rows from the list which contain values in `Edit Text`.

The problem is if rows goes out of the view when scrolling. I'm not getting those rows when the `Button` is clicked.

```
doneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AddedItems = new ArrayList<productinfo>();
        try {
            for(int i = 0;i<allProducts.size();i++) {   
                View view = productListView.getChildAt(i);
                TextView product = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_textview);
                String pName = product.getText().toString();
                TextView p_code = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.product_code);
                String pCode = p_code.getText().toString();
                TextView p_price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price_textview);
                String pPrice = p_price.getText().toString();
                EditText qty = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity_edittext);
                String qtyVal = qty.getText().toString();

                if(qty.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                    //do nothing
                } else {
                    AddedItems.add(new productinfo(pCode, pName, "", pPrice, "",qtyVal));
                    addedProduct.removeAllViews();
                }
            }
```

And this is the adapter:

```
private List<productinfo> products;
    private List<productinfo> arrayList;
    private Context context;
    private String[] tmp;
    private int value;

    public ProductListAdapter(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<productinfo> products) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, resource, products);
        this.context=context;
        this.products=products;
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<productinfo>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(products);
        tmp = new String[products.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public productinfo getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return products.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHoldr holder;

        if(convertView == null){

            holder = new ViewHoldr();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_row_layout, null);

            holder.productCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_code);
            holder.productDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_textview);
            holder.productPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price_textview);
            holder.quantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_edittext);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHoldr) convertView.getTag();          
        }

        holder.ref = position;

        final productinfo product = products.get(position);

         //int colorPos = position % colors.length;
           // convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

        if(product !=null){


            if(holder.productCode!=null)
                holder.productCode.setText(product.getP_CODE());

            if(holder.productDescription!=null)
                holder.productDescription.setText(product.getP_NAME());

            if(holder.productPrice!=null)
                holder.productPrice.setText(product.getMRP());

            //holder.quantity.setText(product.getP_qty());

            holder.quantity.setText(tmp[position]);

            holder.quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    tmp[holder.ref] = s.toString(); 
                }
            });


               //check for odd or even to set alternate colors to the row background
               if(position % 2 == 0){  
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6897bb"));
               }
               else {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cbd3db"));
               }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHoldr
    {
        TextView productCode;
        TextView productDescription;
        TextView productPrice;
        EditText quantity;
        int ref;
    }
```

This is the layout for row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10"
    >

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_code"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4.3"
        android:text="jshadb"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:text="464.89"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/quantity_edittext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:inputType="number"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the layout used in my activity to display rows:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/addedProduct"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:divider="@drawable/vertical_divider" 
        android:dividerPadding="5dp"      
        >

    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is for dialog:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
     <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header_layout"
            android:layout_above="@id/done_button"
            android:id="@+id/product_listview"
             />


    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Done"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/done_button" />
<RelativeLayout />
```

Comment: why are you not using done button with adapter? if button with row of listview.

Comment: sorry to mention....my button is in the layout....

Comment: show your both layout files.

Comment: i have added the layouts please check........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get all the child row views from a ListView simply because a ListView holds only the views for the visible rows. The correct way to do what you want is to store whatever data in the adapter's data and retrieve it from there.

So, you should use this :

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

Instead of just `getChild` from `ListView`

Comment: @NikMyers When I use this, the value from EditText inside my listview doesn't return the value. It works with getChildAt but only for visible rows.
getAdapter().getView() doesn't return any updated value from my edittext